# Why offline scope is added automatically in Microsoft Identity Platform

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-identity-platform

I am trying to use [Microsoft Graph api's using OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user)

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=https://mytestenv&response_type=code&prompt=select_account&scope=User.Read

Even though i provided **User.Read** scope. OAuth consent screen lists offline permission also.

[image: Permissions]

How to remove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to read this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#offline_access.

> This permission currently appears on all consent pages, even for flows
> that don't provide a refresh token (such as the implicit flow). This
> setup addresses scenarios where a client can begin within the implicit
> flow and then move to the code flow where a refresh token is expected.
>
> On the Microsoft identity platform (requests made to the v2.0
> endpoint), your app must explicitly request the offline_access scope,
> to receive refresh tokens.

It’s **not currently possible** to remove the offline_access scope from the initial consent screen when using the v2 endpoint with an AAD account. There is a feedback of this issue [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/34738855-azure-ad-v2-0-oauth2-account-consent-page-always-l).